# C# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance > of an object

Tags: c#

I am working on developing a playing cards game in C# as part of my training in this new language. I have received several errors that I have been able to Google Fu and work out on my own, but this current error of:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object
>   at Deck..ctor () [0x00087] in :0
>   at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at Deck..ctor () [0x00087] in :0
>   at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0

has me blocked. I have tried a few different ways of refactoring `public class Card` and the `Card` constructor function, but I just get different errors and more errors and don't get any closer to resolving it as what the error message above is telling me is that I haven't correctly initialized the object `Card card = new Card(rank, suit);`

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public class Deck {
      // public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();
      public List<Card> cards;

  public Deck() {
      string[] ranks = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
      string[] suits = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

      foreach (string suit in suits) {
          foreach (string rank in ranks) {
              Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
              cards.add(card);
          }
      }
  }
}

public class Card {
    // properties
    public string suit { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }

    public Card(string rank, string suit){
       //initializations
       rank = rank;
       suit = suit;
    }
}
```

I looked through similar posts, but they are not specific to my case and I have also been following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer#example

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is `null` (probably `cards`), then make it not null.

Comment: You have the correct code in place, commented out.

Comment: Additionally, it should be `this.suit = suit;` in the `Card` constructor, and same for rank.

Comment: Change `public List<Card> cards;` to `public List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();`

Comment: Thanks, this helps, I still get `error CS0103: The name cards does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @Daniel hey List has "Add" method. you are using "add"

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule, thanks, I was just working on that, part of the problem looks like is I needed to write it like this `Cards.Add(card);`, referencing `public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();`

Comment: Your `Card` class probably ought to include a Value property.  "Ace" and "Queen" are hard to evaluate for things like a straight in poker or the hand score in Blackjack. Plus, in many games card values can differ from the rank.  The most common example is an Ace in Blackjack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cards` is null. You should initialize it, as was done in the commented-out line above it.